# Display Tooltip into ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a Custom Tooltip control that displays photograph of a student from a binded image source.

But I don't know how to insert this tooltip into my ListView so that whenever I hover over to any ListView Item, it displays corresponding student's photo.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**App.xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" x:Key="CustomToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate 
            TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                CornerRadius="4">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=StudentPhotoFile}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow:**

```
      <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <CheckBox Name="IsPassed" IsChecked="{Binding IsPassed, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Student" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Student}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Class" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Class}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Marks" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Marks}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPassed}">
                                <DataTrigger.Value>false</DataTrigger.Value>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPassed}" >
                                <DataTrigger.Value>true</DataTrigger.Value>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>                           
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListViewItem tooltip WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471309/listviewitem-tooltip-wpf)

Comment: This ain't duplicate. @tzrm

Answer (score 0):

Set the ListView's `ShowItemToolTips` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ItemContainerStyle` of your `ListView` add a setter for `ToolTip`

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource CustomToolTip}"/>
```